# AutoCAD and WMS/WFS

Tags: wms, wfs, autocad-map

I am setting up a mapping server and I wondered if there is anyway to get AutoCAD to access WMS/WFS layers.

I am aware of the fact that AutoCAD Map can do this, but we just have AutoCAD and AutoCAD LT here and could not really justify buying lots of AutoCAD Map licenses.

Is it possible for us to have one copy of AutoCAD Map to set up drawings with WMS layers in the background and then view these drawings in normal AutoCAD or AutoCAD LT?

Are there any third party add ons that enable this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately, it is not possible to view saved WMS layer in AutoCAD or AutoCAD LT, because it is functionality of AutoCAD Map/Civil3D and FDO.
Also I'm not aware of any plugin for WMS in standard AutoCAD/LT.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this yet But planned to. 
You could download the OE for Civil3d (object enabler), But you would need at least one seat of map, to set up the dwg with FDO, save the dwg and then open that dwg in autocad standard with the OE installed. As stated I have not tried this but it could potentially work. This is essentially how I worked around using georeferenced Sid and ECW images in Autocad standard and it did work.
Post back results if you are able to. If I get the chance in the next few days I will attempt it. My only problem will be getting ahold of autocad standard. If I can't I may send a dwg for you to try.

Comment: not sure how to contact privately, maybe moderator can help? I have a dwg posted to my skydrive, I may just post url here if mod doesn't intervene.

Comment: Public url  http://cid-c754c68262a316dc.skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=C754C68262A316DC!109&authkey=6l1EFHd0qnY%24

Comment: I got one of our CAD technicians to test this out. We installed the OE for Civil3D, and we opened the drawing in AutoCAD. All we get is two polylines. Is there supposed to be a background layers?

Comment: Too bad, That should have been an image of washington dc. The wms is found at this url  http://wms.lizardtech.com/lizardtech/iserv/ows?version=1.3.0

Comment: Let me try again. I selected the cache wms this time. See if that helps dwg with _2

Comment: I just saw a link stating that ESRI arcgis for autocad does (Kinda) support wms. >http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-autocad/index.html

Comment: Why would you need OE for civil 3d. Civil 3d (at least recent versions) can also connect to fdo and convert to dwg?

Comment: @johanvdw - OP states he doesn't have map/civil3d or the like, only autocad and lt.